# SQL Server: group by a column and get the first group

Tags: sql-server

I have a table for sending scheduled sms. some texts has multiple receivers, the records with the same text, has the same **GroupID** each time I should select a maximum of 100 receivers but all must have the same GroupID. for example if there are 500 records with the same GroupID I should select 100 records of that group, but if there are 10 records with the same GroupID, I should only select these 10 records.
Well I can simply select top 100 for defining maximum the problem is I don't know how to avoid selection of records with other GroupIDs.

I come up with this solution what do you think?

```
select top 100 * from ScheduledSms
where GroupID = (select top 1 GroupID from ScheduledSms order by DateAdded)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I used my own solution and it works fine:

```
select top 100 * from ScheduledSms
where GroupID = (select top 1 GroupID from ScheduledSms order by DateAdded)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 100 receiver 
WHERE  groupid = '...'
```

Comment: I don't know the groupids, I just want the query to return the first group (what ever its groupid is)